# Are nested classes inside an interface implicitly static and final?

Tags: java, interface, nested

All variables inside of interface are public static and final.

So if I declare a nested class inside an interface will it also become static and final?

```
Interface I
{
    class c
    {
        static void m(){ }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm asking Inner classes inside of interface are static?

Comment: Why its not final

Comment: If it was inner it woudlnt be static. You mean 'nested' class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets find out. Lets create structure like:

```
interface Interface{
    class Foo{}
}
```

Now we can test:

```
System.out.println("static: " + Modifier.isStatic(Interface.Foo.class.getModifiers()));
System.out.println("final: " + Modifier.isFinal(Interface.Foo.class.getModifiers()));
```

which prints:

```
static: true
final: false
```

So nested classes are implicitly static, but not final.

We can confirm it also by adding `class Bar extends Foo{}` to our interface. `final` classes can't be extended but since such code compiles fine it means `Foo` is not final.

Comment: Worth noting, Foo *could* be made final but it would need to be done so *explicitly*, just like any final class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why it is not final ??

Comment: @ShimbuGowda this is the wrong question. The right question would be: why should it be final? Or rather: is there any reason to set all inner classes in interfaces final? There is a necessity to set the inner class static since non-static inner classes always "bind" to a concrete instance of the surrounding class. Because you cannot instantiate interfaces, non-static inner classes have no well-defined semantics and therefore all inner classes in interfaces are implicitly static. There is no necessity to set all inner classes final though.

Comment: @ShimbuGowda What makes you think it should be final? Types (like classes, interfaces, enums) have different purpose than variables, or methods so different rules apply for them.

Comment: @ShimbuGowda final on fields has a different semantics than final on classes. final on a field means, the field (once assigned) can not be reassigned. final on a class means, there must not be any sub-class of this class. While all members of an interface act as constants there is no reason why you should not be allowed to subclass a nested class of an interface.

Answer (score 5):

Classes nested inside interfaces behave like `static` classes nested inside classes, in the sense that you do not need to have an instance of an outer class in order to construct an instance of a nested class. According to [Java Language Specification, §8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3):

> 8.1.3 **Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances**
>
> [...] A member class of an interface is implicitly static (§9.5) so is never considered to be an inner class.

However, these classes are not final, unless you explicitly designate them as such. This makes sense, because classes that implement an interface may need an opportunity to extend nested classes defined inside the interface.