# Java inherit from contained class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following class relationship in my code:

```
public class A implements A.IA
{
    private IA value;

    private static class B implements IA

    private static class C implements IA

    private interface IA //implicitly static
}
```

My IDE tells me that this is a form of cyclic inheritance involving `A`. I would not think that the inheritance itself is cyclic, but that they do definitely have a cyclic relationship of some sort.
Could someone explain why this is an issue? I understand that inheriting from non-static members is impossible, as a non-static method is tied to an instance of its containing class, but a static member has no such requirement. What is it about this relationship that makes inheritance impossible?

### Note

I already have a partial solution to this problem, below, though it is unsatisfactory because `IA` is no longer allowed to be private. While I'm mostly after an explanation of the problem above, different solutions would be appreciated.

```
public class A implements IA
{
    private IA value;

    private static class B implements IA

    private static class C implements IA
}

interface IA
```

Comment: how do you see this logically happening? A can't exist, until it implements IA, and IA doesn't exist until A exists.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want `IA` to be private? This seems to be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). One crude and dirty solution would be to wrap your working solution in a `class Outer`, allowing you to set `private interface IA`.

Comment: @Stultuske I guess I don't know the details of how class initialisation works in java, but I figured that a static nested class wouldn't need to wait for the instantiation of the containing class. Your argument seems similar to saying that a class cannot have a member of its own type.

Comment: @ZoeyHewll static members don't, but when you say: private interface IA ... -> that's not static.

Comment: @Stultuske My IDE (IntelliJ Idea) indicated that `static interface` was redundant for an inner interface, hence my comment "Implicitly static". The code produces the same warning with `static interface`.

Comment: @Turing85 I ask this question mostly out of curiosity for the cause of the problem, not out of need of a solution. It is unlikely that `IA` will ever need to be seen outside of the file, so I figure private access is preferred, though package-private is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Like what Stultuske has mentioned in the comments, it does not make sense to create a class which uses an interface defined by itself. The reverse makes sense, though.

The class `A` can not compile successfully before you successfully compile `A.IA`. On the other hand, `A.IA` can only compile when its enclosing class is being compiled.

The next nearest thing you can do for interface `IA` is to move it to the same package, and make it package-private.

Another way is to wrap everything into another class again, and move the interface `IA` one layer out.

Comment: Is this the case even for static members? [@Stultuske's second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48221988/java-inherit-from-contained-class?noredirect=1#comment83425500_48221988) indicated that static members wouldn't have this restriction, but I can understand if they would.

Comment: @ZoeyHewll The thread opener's point of inner interface being implicitly static is [true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541045/are-nested-classes-inside-an-interface-implicitly-static-and-final).

Comment: @ZoeyHewll The person asking the question. Just to elaborate a bit, there is no difference of static or non-static at compile-time. No matter how you write your class, one .java file is still going to be compiled into one .class file.

Comment: it seems unwise to say there is no difference; there is a distinct difference in how static and non-static members are interpreted at compile-time (eg the compiler can pick up on things like a static method accessing any non-static member). Do you instead mean that _this situation_ doesn't depend on whether the member is static or not?

Comment: @ZoeyHewll That kind of difference is different from what we are talking about. The difference of having `static` or not like like the difference of using `public` and `private`. In this case, the compiler tries to compile the outer class first, then it says "Oh, it implements `IA`, let's wait for that to compile first. The compiler will only know what kind of characteristics `IA` would provide after it has a compiled `IA`, so that it knows how to compile the outer class. Unfortunately, that just won't happen because that its child.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misconception in your class hierarchy: It doesn't make sense to expose externally that class A implements an interface if this interface is not visible externally. I don't see any practical use for that.

Comment: That is a valid point. While I can imagine situations where `A` `B` and `C` might need to be referred to via this common interface within the file, it definitely is only for convenience (of documentation and default methods) in my case.